# Protect against CRSF stateless

Tags: api, rest, stateless

**Context**

I m actually building a REST API, a simple one and I need to protect against CSRF attacks. The fact is that I m stateless, using tokens, and so, I cant compare with the CSRF in sessions...

**Question**

Does a pattern, or a good practice excist in other to manage CSRF protection in a completely stateless environments without using sessions ?

Answer (score 0):

If your API will authenticate the user you can always use oauth2 and it will prevent CSRF attack. Now if you do not need authentication you can always use a reverse proxy that will do the job for you so you will not have to take care of CSRF anymore in your application layer.

Comment: OAUth2 prevents from CSRF ?

Comment: In a way yes, how would you forge a request in presence of an oauth token. See the wiki page about CSRF.